# Solving a sparse matrix equation with Pardiso, created with armadillo

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, armadillo, pardiso

I wanted to use the Pardiso-Solver from the MKL instead of the build-in sparse matrix solver. For that I first create the matrix in armadillo, and then convert it into a CSC-matrix which is put into the Pardiso-solver. My code is

```
int main()
{
    /* Matrix data. */
    MKL_INT n = 8;
    arma::sp_mat single_mat = arma::sp_mat(n, n);
    single_mat.diag(-2).fill(1);
    single_mat.diag(-1).fill(-8);
    single_mat.diag(0).fill(0);
    single_mat.diag(1).fill(8);
    single_mat.diag(2).fill(-1);
    single_mat = single_mat / 0.0012;
    std::cout << "Number of nonzeros: " << single_mat.n_nonzero << '\n';
    std::cout << "Number of n_cols: " << single_mat.n_cols << '\n';
    MKL_INT *ia = new MKL_INT[single_mat.n_cols+1];
    MKL_INT *ja = new MKL_INT[single_mat.n_nonzero];
    double *a = new double[single_mat.n_nonzero];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < single_mat.n_nonzero; i++)
        ja[i] = single_mat.row_indices[i];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < single_mat.n_nonzero; i++)
        a[i] = single_mat.values[i];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < single_mat.n_cols+1; i++)
        ia[i] = single_mat.col_ptrs[i];


    std::cout << "\n" << arma::mat(single_mat) << "\n";

    MKL_INT mtype = 11;       /* Real symmetric matrix */
                              /* RHS and solution vectors. */
    double *b = new double[n], *x = new double[n], *bs = new double[n], res, res0;
    bs[0] = 0;
    bs[1] = 0;
    MKL_INT nrhs = 1;     /* Number of right hand sides. */
                          /* Internal solver memory pointer pt, */
                          /* 32-bit: int pt[64]; 64-bit: long int pt[64] */
                          /* or void *pt[64] should be OK on both architectures */
    void *pt[64];
    /* Pardiso control parameters. */
    MKL_INT iparm[64];
    MKL_INT maxfct, mnum, phase, error, msglvl;
    /* Auxiliary variables. */
    MKL_INT i;
    double ddum;          /* Double dummy */
    MKL_INT idum;         /* Integer dummy. */
                          /* -------------------------------------*/
                          /* .. Setup Pardiso control parameters. */
                          /* -------------------------------------*/
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        iparm[i] = 0;
    }
    iparm[0] = 1;         /* No solver default */
    iparm[1] = 2;         /* Fill-in reordering from METIS */
    iparm[3] = 0;         /* No iterative-direct algorithm */
    iparm[4] = 0;         /* No user fill-in reducing permutation */
    iparm[5] = 0;         /* Write solution into x */
    iparm[7] = 2;         /* Max numbers of iterative refinement steps */
    iparm[9] = 13;        /* Perturb the pivot elements with 1E-13 */
    iparm[10] = 1;        /* Use nonsymmetric permutation and scaling MPS */
    iparm[12] = 0;        /* Maximum weighted matching algorithm is switched-off (default for symmetric). Try iparm[12] = 1 in case of inappropriate accuracy */
    iparm[13] = 0;        /* Output: Number of perturbed pivots */
    iparm[17] = -1;       /* Output: Number of nonzeros in the factor LU */
    iparm[18] = -1;       /* Output: Mflops for LU factorization */
    iparm[19] = 0;        /* Output: Numbers of CG Iterations */
    iparm[26] = 1;        /* Checks if matrix is correct*/
    iparm[34] = 1;        /* PARDISO use C-style indexing for ia and ja arrays */
    maxfct = 1;           /* Maximum number of numerical factorizations. */
    mnum = 1;         /* Which factorization to use. */
    msglvl = 0;           /* Print statistical information in file */
    error = 0;            /* Initialize error flag */
                          /* ----------------------------------------------------------------*/
                          /* .. Initialize the internal solver memory pointer. This is only  */
                          /*   necessary for the FIRST call of the PARDISO solver.           */
                          /* ----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        pt[i] = 0;
    }
    /* --------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* .. Reordering and Symbolic Factorization. This step also allocates  */
    /*    all memory that is necessary for the factorization.              */
    /* --------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    phase = 11;
    PARDISO(pt, &maxfct, &mnum, &mtype, &phase,
        &n, a, ia, ja, &idum, &nrhs, iparm, &msglvl, &ddum, &ddum, &error);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        printf("\nERROR during symbolic factorization: %d", error);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nReordering completed ... ");
    printf("\nNumber of nonzeros in factors = %d", iparm[17]);
    printf("\nNumber of factorization MFLOPS = %d", iparm[18]);
    /* ----------------------------*/
    /* .. Numerical factorization. */
    /* ----------------------------*/
    phase = 22;
    PARDISO(pt, &maxfct, &mnum, &mtype, &phase,
        &n, a, ia, ja, &idum, &nrhs, iparm, &msglvl, &ddum, &ddum, &error);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        printf("\nERROR during numerical factorization: %d", error);
        exit(2);
    }
    printf("\nFactorization completed ... ");
    /* -----------------------------------------------*/
    /* .. Back substitution and iterative refinement. */
    /* -----------------------------------------------*/
    phase = 33;
    iparm[7] = 2;         /* Max numbers of iterative refinement steps. */
                          /* Set right hand side to one. */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[i] = 1;
    }
    PARDISO(pt, &maxfct, &mnum, &mtype, &phase,
        &n, a, ia, ja, &idum, &nrhs, iparm, &msglvl, b, x, &error);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        printf("\nERROR during solution: %d", error);
        exit(3);
    }
    printf("\nSolve completed ... ");
    printf("\nThe solution of the system is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n x [%d] = % f", i, x[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //Check with Lapack solve
    arma::colvec b_vec = arma::colvec(n);
    b_vec.fill(1);
    arma::colvec x_vec = arma::zeros(n);
    arma::spsolve(x_vec, single_mat, b_vec, "lapack");


    //End Lapack
    printf("\nx_vec is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n x [%d] = % f", i, x_vec[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //Check resolutions
    arma::colvec x_pardiso = arma::colvec(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        x_pardiso[i] = x[i];

    std::cout << "\n" << single_mat*x_pardiso << '\n' << single_mat*x_vec << '\n';

    /* --------------------------------------*/
    /* .. Termination and release of memory. */
    /* --------------------------------------*/
    phase = -1;           /* Release internal memory. */
    PARDISO(pt, &maxfct, &mnum, &mtype, &phase,
        &n, &ddum, ia, ja, &idum, &nrhs,
        iparm, &msglvl, &ddum, &ddum, &error);
    std::cout << "\nPardiso freed memory\n";
    delete[]a;
    delete[]ja;
    delete[]ia;
    delete[]x;
    delete[]b;
    delete[]bs;
    return 0;
}
```

I check the result using the `Lapack`-solver from armadillo. But while the latter one gives me the correct result, I do not get a correct result from the `pardiso`-solver. My current output is

```
The solution of the system is:
 x [0] =  0.000674
 x [1] = -0.000089
 x [2] =  0.000488
 x [3] = -0.000287
 x [4] =  0.000288
 x [5] = -0.000487
 x [6] =  0.000089
 x [7] = -0.000677

x_vec is:
 x [0] = -0.000673
 x [1] =  0.000089
 x [2] = -0.000487
 x [3] =  0.000287
 x [4] = -0.000287
 x [5] =  0.000487
 x [6] = -0.000089
 x [7] =  0.000673
```

The values for x_vec are correct, the values for x are not. Why?

Comment: Are you wondering about the inverted sign (x=-x_vec, approx), or the rounding differences? The rounding error could be introduced by different rounding/truncation rules, except the last one (x[7]) which looks weird.

Comment: I am wondering about both, especially when testing `Ax=b` afterwards, the correct values for `x` gives me the original value for `b`, but the incorrect values do not.

Comment: Well, sign mistakes happen. Could be due to different implementation of the algorithm, different implementation of the matrix (accidentally transposing it for example) or similar. Maybe changing to CSR/CRS format helps? I dont have MKL here, so can't help testing.

Comment: When increasing the value for `n`, the differences get bigger, even if the signs are adjusted, thus the errors are even bigger. Furthermore, I am currently using the CSC-format, due to both armadillo and mkl supporting it, thus I assume that there should not be a problem.